# Overriding the Backbone.Model constructor?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to override the constructor on my `Backbone.Model` to adjust the attributes passed to the parent constructor. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Models.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    constructor: function (attributes, options) {
        Backbone.Model.apply(this, this.parse(attributes), options);
    },
    parse: function (attributes) { .... }
)};
```

My problem is that the parent constructor is invoked with undefined parameters.

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L254

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    var attrs = attributes || {};
    options || (options = {});
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
    this.attributes = {};
    if (options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
    if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
    attrs = _.defaults({}, attrs, _.result(this, 'defaults'));
    this.set(attrs, options);
    this.changed = {};
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

The `attributes` and `options` arguments are both undefined, which means the model instantiated with the default parameters.

Now I could override the `initialize` method and unset the bad attributes, replacing it with the correct attributes. But that just seems like a hack.

Why is the parent constructor being invoked with undefined arguments?

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you posting a question you already know the answer to? If you post a question at least have the decency of giving others a chance to answer it.

Comment: Because I figured it out while asking the question and wanted to write it down. Feel free to provide your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is to do with the semantics of `Function.`[apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and `Function.`[call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

`apply` expects two arguments, a given `this` value and an array of arguments.

`call` expects `n + 1` arguments, a given `this` value and `n` arguments to be passed to the function.

```
Backbone.Model.apply(this, this.parse(attributes), options);
```

Should be:

```
Backbone.Model.call(this, this.parse(attributes), options);
```

Or

```
Backbone.Model.apply(this, [this.parse(attributes), options]);
```

Calling the `apply` function as I was leads to undefined variables.